# Prove that there are $n$-dimensional polytopes that don't have any diagonal for any positive integer $n\geq2$.

Tags: geometry, combinatorial-geometry, polytopes

My friend happened to find a question on Combinatorial Geometry. We know that in $2$ dimensional Euclidean Plane triangles have no diagonal; and, in $3$ dimensional space, Tetrahedrons have no diagonal. So, naturally, a question comes in mind about higher dimensions.

> The question is to prove that there exists $n$-dimensional polytopes that don't have any diagonal for any positive integer $n\geq2$.

Comment: The analogue of the triangle and tetrahedron is the $n$-dimensional [simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex).

Comment: @Blue But how to prove it?

Comment: The edge-structure of a simplex is the "complete graph" on $(n+1)$ vertices: every vertex is joined to every other. no diagonals. Geometrically, go up one dimension and use the convenient coordinatization where the $(n+1)$ vertices lie at the points $(1,0,0,\ldots,0)$, $(0,1,0, \ldots,0)$, $(0,0,1, \ldots, 0,0)$, $\ldots$, $(0,0,0,\ldots, 1)$. The "convex hull" of these points is a polytope for which every pair of vertices determines an edge (so, no diagonals); further, every trio determines a triangular face; every quartet determines a tetrahedral cell; etc. It's pretty straightforward.

Comment: A proof, put simply: in a simplex, every vertex is connected to every other vertex by an edge, so there can't possibly be a diagonal connecting two vertices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A triangle has no diagonal. - Obvious.
2. A tetrahedron is nothing but
   the pyramid on the base of a triangle. Thus the height (as a
   potential diagonal wrt. the top vertex) obviously hits the bottom
   facet (here: triangle face) perpendicularily. Putting this together with the
   fact that the tetrahedron is regular (and thus esp. both vertex- and
   facet- (here: triangle face) transitive), you'd get this assumption here too.
3. Finally note that the arguments provided in step 2. will apply for all
   simplices of any further dimension as well.

--- rk